# How can I "composer require" just Doctrine ORM EntityManagerInterface

Tags: orm, doctrine, composer-php, require

My recently created package rely on repository interfaces. One of the choices for a source data is database and Doctrine ORM. As database is just one of possible choices, I do not want to integrate the whole Doctrine ORM package, but to create an appropriate adapter that just depends on Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface. The question is how can I "composer require" partially from Doctrine ORM ? I'd like to add, that I could not have found any separate package with the Doctrine ORM EntityManagerInterface.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to just require a single class/interface from a package. What you could do instead is require [doctrine/persistence](https://github.com/doctrine/persistence). This library provides persistence interfaces which are then used by Doctrine ORM/ODM. Instead of relying on the [`EntityManagerInterface`](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManagerInterface.php) you would then rely on the [`ObjectManager`](https://github.com/doctrine/persistence/blob/1.3.x/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/ObjectManager.php)-interface.

If you want to neither rely on doctrine/orm nor doctrine/persistence then you should use `require-dev` and `suggests` to allow for using those dependencies during development, e.g. for writing tests against the Doctrine EntityManager, and to inform users of your library which persistence libraries you explicitly support and require those as well.

You could also create your own `EntityManagerInterface` and then provide a second package for integration with different providers which then implement that interface in an adapter. So instead of pulling doctrine/orm into your library, you expose your interface and provide custom libraries for data providers like doctrine/orm. This way you inverse the dependency requirement, but unfortunately you will have more maintenance work. You can look at projects like [php-http/httplug](https://github.com/php-http/httplug) and the corresponding php-http/*-client packages for inspiration. They have a similar approach when it comes to integrating multiple clients (guzzle, curl, ...) and provide a common abstraction on top of them.

Comment: Thank you. It's a great answer.